# Is it necessary to uninstall first before updating .deb package?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

Once in a while I install a .deb package which is not available via package archive (i.e. `dpkg -i some-package-v1.deb`).

I wonder if I should uninstall these packages before updating in order to remain clean. I mean when I do `dpkg -i some-package-v2.deb` what happens to the previously installed files of version v1? Will they be removed automatically?

Comment: Depends on whether the one who made these packages made sane packages. Correctly made packages shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: @muru `dpkg` will do a normal upgrade. I do not see what can be wrong with a package.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have seen cases where maintainers moved files between pairs of related packages, without declaring any conflicts. dpkg errors out when the new package A1 tries to overwrite old package A2's files.

Comment: In this case the error will show the problem if dependencies are not met, etc. In case there are no errors, it should be OK.

Answer (score 6):

- No, you don't have to remove previously installed one.
- However, it depends on the package quality. Myself I don't uninstall first only if I already faced a problem.

  The normal update installation just remove the previous keeping the configuration files then install new one. `dpkg` will ask you to overwrite or keep previous config file if it is in `/etc` and they are different.

  If I'm going to remove 1st then I do *purge* instead that will remove all files including the configuration ones.

  ```
    dpkg -P package...
    dpkg --purge package...
  ```
- This post shows the upgrade flow diagram: https://askubuntu.com/a/1116587/26246
- Upstream documentation here:  https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-flowcharts.html

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to uninstall the package. If you run

```
dpkg -i some-package-v2.deb
```

the old version will be replaced by the new one. All files will be overwritten. This is a normal way to upgrade a package without using repositories.

Comment: This is generally true for packages from the same packager but if you are using ppa or other non standard repos it might be safer to uninstal first